# How to prevent keyboard from turning off, when closing laptop lid in Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, acpi, tablet-mode

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X201 Tablet with buttons on the screen bezel. These buttons are there to rotate or invert the display in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) or lock the screen. Currently I have successfully configured the buttons to do this. However, they are part of the same keyboard input device `/dev/input/event3`.

This means that the keyboard is disabled when the lid is closed. However, it also means that when the X201 Tablet is in tablet mode, it disabled the keyboard. Therefore when I enter tablet mode, I cannot use the bezel buttons even though they are still reachable and meant to be used in tablet mode.

I am certain, that it is able to tell the difference from being in tablet mode or actually being closed, since the screen doesn't turn off in tablet mode, but it does when when closing it like a normal laptop.

Is there a way to prevent Linux from disabling the keyboard, when I close the lid or maybe even only when in tablet mode?
-and if that is possible, would it also be possible to only enable the four bezel buttons and disable the rest of the keyboard?

Comment: Not super elegant, but this guy wrote a script to do it... he also mentions how to find the name of your keyboard, which ,may help determine if the bezel buttons are the same keyboard or seperate at all. https://askubuntu.com/questions/867350/can-i-make-my-keyboard-disable-enter-tablet-mode-when-folding-back-my-display

Comment: Thank you, this did help me a lot. However, it appears that the reason could be because I enter `-event6   SWITCH_TOGGLE    +0.457s switch tablet-mode state 1
 event6   SWITCH_TOGGLE    +38.721s switch tablet-mode state 0`, which might turn off the keyboard (and therefore the bezel buttons which are part of the keyboard event). Would you know if there is a way to modify what the `tablet-mode` disables?